# I've never logged into LinkedIn, but I receive update notifications

Tags: linkedin

I've never subscribed to LinkedIn.  To me it's a virus.  A past employee, who is no longer with our company, had placed my name in his distribution list of updates.  I don't know how to get in touch with this person nor do I wish to.  He is a complete jackass.  I will not sign into LinkedIn to mail him to remove my name as I don't have an account nor do I want one.

How do I stop these?

In Outlook I have placed them in SPAM but they still get into my junk email and I cannot stop this.

I can supply the name of the individual if Customer Service can go in and block or delete my name from his list.

Comment: You are going to have to contact LinkedIn directly on this. Without creating an account I doubt there's anything you can do on the site.

Comment: Just curious: why do you care if they're in your spam/junk folders?

Comment: Isn't there an unsubscribe link in the emails? If not, try a 'whois' search for the originating domain and look for an admin contact to report it as abuse. I've had good luck with this when the company has assets in the US, as LinkedIn does.

Comment: You have to have an account with _anyone_ who you want to never contact you -- they can't tell they shouldn't contact you without an account on their system containing that preference.

Comment: @MikeScott.  Not so.  Under EU privacy law, sending ANY unsolicited email is a criminal offence punishable by unlimited fine.  In theory you only need to give them an email address and tell them never to send to it.  In practice of course it isn't so easy.

Comment: @Chenmunka It's obvious nonsense to say that sending any unsolicited email is illegal, or no one could ever email anyone else. From how many of your friends do you have a signed waiver agreeing that you can email them? Unsolicited commercial email may be illegal, but this is non-commercial email from one individual to another sent via a commercial service, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @MikeScott.  That's right.  Politicians know nothing of the real world. Which is why I say it isn't easy in practice.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn is an unstoppable and unwinnable spammer, there is no way to really unsubscribe. To avoid receiving their emails, I registered and disabled all emails in the settings. Once you've done that, you can forget LinkedIn forever.

When you can't beat them, join them.

Otherwise, if you want to choose a longer route and if you are in a lucky country with privacy protection, you can of course complain to the relevant authority: http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/bodies/authorities/index_en.htm